# Excel - Search for pairs of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I look up pairs of cells with the *find and select* option of Microsoft Excel 2016?

My goal is to find a pair of cells like the selected ones below:
[image]

Is it possible to use a seperator such as for example <kbd>,</kbd> to split the term searched into multiple cells?

(For example, I would type the following to find the two cells):
[image]
Disregarding the options selected.

Is my goal achievable or do I need to use a function or script of some sort to identify where these cells are?

Comment: AFAIK you can't find cells like you're trying to.  What you can do, is add a helper column that is (assuming the names are in C and D columns, `=c1&", "&d1`. Then just search "Curie Ewa, Marie Curie`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the filter? If you filter on both columns if they are in the same row you'll get result(s). If there is no row where both show up you will get an empty filtered result.